# Categorize errors according to table criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to categorize errors based on the number of times they occur in a timespan.
I have made a 'A', 'B' and 'C' category to indicate how often the error occurs. Also I have a 'Z' category if the error does not occur often enough to fit the criterias of 'A', 'B' and 'C'.
Note that the user can add as many categories as they want ('D', 'E', 'F' etc..)

I've made a query which almost gives the correct result, but I need to filter off the criterias which is "downstream" in the criteria order, because some errors will fit multiple criterias.

Tables:

```
errors
ErrorNo ErrorName
1       'Error 1'
2       'Error 2'
3       'Error 3'
4       'Error 4'

errorLog
errorNo timestamp
1       2019-04-26  --1 time each day the last 6 days
1       2019-04-25
1       2019-04-24
1       2019-04-23
1       2019-04-22
1       2019-04-21

2       2019-04-26  --3 times today
2       2019-04-26
2       2019-04-26

3       2019-04-26
3       2019-03-26  --1 month ago

errorCategoryTypes
categoryName    months  minErrorCnt
A               1       6       --means at least 6 times the last 1 month
B               1       2       --means at least 2 times the last 1 month
C               3       1       --means at least 1 times the last 3 month
```

Sql query:

```
select errors.errorNo
, case when category.categoryName is not null then category.categoryName else 'Z' end
from errors
left join (
    select errorNo, categoryName
    from errorLog
    join errorCategoryTypes on errorLog.timestamp between DATEADD(day,-(errorCategoryTypes.months * 30),getdate()) and GETDATE()
    group by errorNo, categoryName, errorCategoryTypes.minErrorCnt
    having COUNT(errorLog.id) >= errorCategoryTypes.minErrorCnt
) category on errors.errorNo = category.errorNo
group by errors.errorNo, category.categoryName
```

It produces the following result, because 'Error 1' actually fits all 'A', 'B' and 'C' criterias and 'B' fits both 'B' and 'C'. But how do I stop the calculation when it finds a fit?

```
ErrorNo Category

1       A           
1       B           
1       C           
2       B
2       C           
3       C           
4       Z
```

I need the following result

```
ErrorNo Category

1       A           --because error 1 occures at least 6 times during the last 1 month
2       B           --because error 2 occures at least 2 times during the last 1 month
3       C           --because error 3 occures at least 1 time during the last 3 months
4       Z           --because error 4 does not fit A, B or C category criterias
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select e.errorno, e.categoryName
from (select e.errorno, e.categoryName,
             count(*) as applicable_errors,
             row_number() over (partition by e.errorno order by e.categoryName) as seqnum
      from error e left join
           errorlog el
           on el.errorno = e.errorno left join
           errorCategoryTypes ect
           on el.timestamp >= dateadd(month, - ect.months, getdate())
      group by e.errorno, e.categoryName, e.
      having count(*) >= minErrorCnt
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This has to rely on the category name for the ordering.  You should have a priority column it the error types table